Confusion regarding the equation $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$
In Reif's Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics he outlines a "proof" (sections 3.8 and 3.9) of the equation $dS=\frac{\delta Q}{T}$ for any quasi-static, infinitesimal process (i.e. any changes of the parameters are infinitesimal). He defines a reversible process as a process where $\Omega_f=\Omega_i$, i.e. the number of states accessible to the system doesn't change. But when I look up the formula for $dS$, I see it given as $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$, which is different than what Reif has.
Im confused because by Reifs definition, any reversal process must have $dQ=0$ or else $dS>0$ (i.e. $\Omega_f \neq \Omega_i$), so the definition of  $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$ doesn't really make sense. I know I'm not being crazy because Reif says "the performance of quasi static work changes the energy of a thermally isolated system but does not affect the number of states accessible to it... such a process is thus reversible" (page 116). His discussion seems to imply that reversible processes are a subset of processes in which $dS=\frac{\delta Q}{T}$ holds, in contrast with the definition $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$. Is Reif wrong? Is he just using different notation? What's the discrepancy?

A quasi static infinitesimal process is a reversible one.

@MattHanson so, from Reif's definition of reversible, this would mean that the formula $dS=\frac{\delta Q}{T}$ only applies when $\delta Q=0$... i.e. $dS=0$. Do you mean that reversible=quasi static+infinitesmal is the standard definition of reversible, and Reif's is not?

In reversible heat transfer, $\delta Q\neq 0$, and $\Delta\Omega$ for the system and heat source/sink are equal and opposite; thus, the total $\Omega_\mathrm{final}=\Omega_\mathrm{initial}$.

@MattHanson I don't understand your comment. Two bodies of different temperature connected by a link with minuscule thermal conductivity can reasonably be modeled as undergoing a quasistatic process of temperature equilibration, but entropy is generated with every infinitesimal energy shift down the thermal gradient. That process is not reversible.

@Chemomechanics I could be overlooking something blatant but if heat can be transferred between two systems, doesn't this nearly always mean $\Omega_f>\Omega_i$? If the two systems have energies $E_1$ , $E_2$ and $E_1+E_2=E$, now isn't $\Omega_f=\sum_{E_i}\Omega^{1} (E_i)\Omega^{2} (E-E_i)>\Omega^{1} (E_1)\Omega^{2} (E_2)=\Omega_i$ (where the summation is over all energies accessible to system 1, and we assume system 1 can assume more energies than just $E_1$). Or am I being stupid (which I now think I am) and this won't apply since the change isn't infinitesimal?

@user62783 But $\Omega_i$ is not necessarily $\Omega^1(E_1)\Omega^2(E_2)$.  There should be summation over $E$ too.

Reif perhaps means that in a reversible process, entropy of the supersystem (the system + the reservoir that exchanges heat with it) remains constant. Together with Boltzmann's/Planck's observation that thermodynamic entropy is proportional to log of number of compatible microstates, this implies that the number of compatible microstates of the supersystem remains constant.
In a reversible process, thermodynamic entropy and thus the number of compatible microstates of the system can change. E.g. in a process where the system does no work, but accepts heat (isochoric heating), both increase.
